# convert an .htaccess to nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I've been trying for weeks to convert rewrite rules from a .htaccess to nginx rewrite.

The original file looked like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

Converted

```
if (!-f $request_filename){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if (!-d $request_filename){
    set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "21"){
    rewrite /.* /index.php?/$0 last;
}
```

But when I restart nginx I get:

> nginx: [emerg] unknown "0" variable
>   nginx: configuration file /usr/local/nginx-1.8/conf/nginx.conf test failed

Answer (score 2):

Automatic converters such [this one](https://winginx.com/en/htaccess) can give you a pretty good start...

```
# nginx configuration
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
         rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$0 break;
    }
}
```

Of course **`if`** is evil, which is why [this manual to converting mod_rewrite directives](https://www.nginx.com/blog/converting-apache-to-nginx-rewrite-rules/)  gives an  even better option

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```